# How to print out the dictionary with for loop? Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, printing

I would like to print the item of dictionary. how to do that?
this is my code

```
{'naruto': [900, 170], 'onepiece': [600, 60]}

for key, value in stock_dict1.items():
        for value in stock_dict1.values():
            print(key, value[0], value[1])
```

when I print out, the result will be like this:
how to do that?

```
naruto      900 170
onepiece    600 60
```

Comment: could you show us what have you tried?

Comment: Why do you need the nested loop? You already get the `value` from the outer loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.ljust` and iterable unpacking:

```
data = {'naruto': [900, 170], 'onepiece': [600, 60]}

for movie, nums in data.items():
    print(movie.ljust(11, ' '), *nums)
```

---

```
naruto      900 170
onepiece    600 60
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet provides the easy way for beginner.

Try this:

```
d = {'naruto': [900, 170], 'onepiece': [600, 60]}

for key in d:
    print(key, end=' ')
    for value in d[key]:
        print(value, end=' ')
    print()
```